How to fairly buy-out a sibling of an inherited house that the other has lived in for over a decade?
I rented my Grandparents house from my father for 2 years before he passed. After he passed the house was put into both my name and my brothers. We did not discuss selling as this was my home and I had a young child. (The property my father lived in upon passing was sold and split 50/50). Over ten years later I still live here but my brother has talked about selling/me paying rent. He has not been responsible for any taxes/property upkeep in the 10+ years. At one point I moved out for 2 years and we discussed renting the property. My brother who lives out of state did not pay for any taxes/bills(heat in winter) on the vacant home during this time or do any maintenance (snow removal, lawn maintenance). He did travel to help get the house ready to be rented a couple times helping with cleaning out the home/garage. We moved back into the home and now there are discussions about paying rent/buying out. Financially I’m in a really tough place. I do believe they deserve a fair amount but where does that number come from? In the years living here plenty of updates have been done by me to increase the homes value. Would that be something that could be deducted? Or the years of paying for the taxes/insurance? I want to be fair and I get that they technically haven’t received their “share” I’m just wondering if these things play a part in how much her share would be worth now especially since it’s vastly different from the value a decade ago haha

I’m voting to close this question because it isn't a legal question (but is asking for specific advice).  There are various threads on the personal finance stack about different ways to approach coming to a fair valuation in a case like this.  But "fairness" is a rather subjective thing so there are many possible answers-- you'd need to understand what you and your family would consider to be fair.

You are an owner.  You don't pay rent to co-owners. You co-own with them. But you've got a fairly complex sounding problem on your hand, which could get difficult if your sibling decides they're going to move in. So best to seek out an actual lawyer that can handle issues with inheritance and real estate.

@zibadawatimmy thank you very much for your response. They live out of state and would never want to move in but they are understandably looking for their share, just wondering what deductions would legally come into play on my end regarding the pay out. Definitely seems like I’ll need a lawyer unfortunately. Thanks again!

It helps to think of the whole thing as a corporation.
Imagine that your father owned a real estate holding company. This company had one asset (the house), one owner (your father), one tenant (your father), and two part-time employees (your father as accountant and your father as handyman/groundskeeper). Imagine the accounts were separate -- your father paying rent from one of his accounts to another, paying property taxes and repairs from that "house account". Doing all this for real would usually be stupid for tax reasons, but think of it that way ...
When your father passed away, this real estate company still had the house, and it had two owners (you and your brother, 50/50), but it was in need of a new tenant and new part-time employees. For some of the time, you were the tenant. For all (?) of the time, you were the accountant.
Calculate the fictional rent you "owe the house," and what "the house owes you" for taxes you paid out of your pocket, etc. Add interest and add the totals. Take the current value of the house, add what you notionally owe the house, divide by two, and that is what your brother is owed from the estate of your father.

Thank you very much for your response and that does make sense. I guess I’m just confused about what/if anything else would fall under the “what the house owes you” category.  Is it only taxes? Or would remodeling/updating the home be included, like a new kitchen?  I see the question was closed so if you can’t answer, no worries, thank you again for your help and breaking everything down with the corporation example

@LauraVitali, a new kitchen should be "paid by the house," but then the house is improved and the "fair rent" goes up. If you can speak to your brother on reasonable terms, you might simply average the minor stuff over the years.

Thank you for clarifying that for me regarding the kitchen. We are really hoping to reach a gentle and reasonable agreement.
